# How to install elementary in a UEFI ASUS system?

Tags: uefi, asus

Please somebody share the installation procedure for UEFI system ASUS.

I am not able to install grub.

Answer (score 1):

You can create UEFI bootable USB drive (I'm use rufus) with elementary OS and boot from it. When you boot from USB with elementary you can install OS as usual and after it you will have two boot options in UEFI (also you can see LAN boot options if you enable it in BIOS):

- Windows Boot manager
- ubuntu

And you can choose main boot option and boot from it. If windows boot loader will be disabled or not present at list you can repair it with bootable Windows USB drive.